# Is it possible to access class members by just its class name in dart 3 without making instance of the class? and how?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, instance

I am creating a class of strings for my flutter applicaion and I want t make all class members static but problem is I want to prevent making instance of that class and I want to acces its members by the class name. Can anyone tell me is there any possiblity of doing it?

I tried making members static but it didn't prevent from making instance.

Comment: You can mark the class as abstract to prevent creating an instance of the class.

Comment: This is considered bad practice in Dart. Instead you could just make your constants top level variables. (If you want to make a class that cannot be instantiated, add a named constructor with name `_` - for example `MyClass._();`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string using your class name, there is no need to create instances, here is a code sample

```
class YourClassName{
  static const String yourString = 'YourString';
}

void main(){
  print(YourClassName.yourString);
}
```

Comment: But if you create the class instance, it will not stop it from creating it. I have found the solution by making the constructor of the class private and its members static.